# What is the difference between OWL and owl carousel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, owl, owl-carousel

Please explain the ***differences*** between **OWL** and **Owl carousel**.
Are they similar in any way? why are they named so?
 Any good sites/tutorials where I can learn both of them.
Which are usually read books for them?
Any sites where I can read books on these online.Also if possible ,please provide some information on good sites/tutorials where I can learn **bootstrap**.Which are usually read books for bootstrap?
Any sites where I can read books on bootstrap online  
THANKS

Answer (score 3):

These two things has nothing in common

**OWL** - stands for Web Ontology Language and it is used for representing knowledge about resources on the web and processing web information. You can read more about it at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Ontology_Language

**OWL Carousel** - jQuery plugin that make it easier to create carousel sliders. http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

Based on your question I guess your interest is in second one. OWL is more used by Semantic Web researchers.

Some of the online tutorials for bootstrap which you can use for initial learning:

http://ieatcss.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial.html

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

http://bootstrap-tutorial.bootstraptor.com/

Comment: Hi,is there any, interactive tutorial for bootstrap.And thanks a lot for the links above.

Comment: I'm not aware of some interactive tutorial, but maybe this interactive docs for bootstrap in combination with some tutorial would be of help for you http://pinegrow.com/bootstrap-docs.html

Comment: Thank you thats very kind @zoran jeremic shall look into these.